# Use variable in javascript object selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I ran into a problem when dynamically attempting to retrieve an object row based on a variable.  What would be a good work around to the following situation?

```
function getDetails(id) {
    completeID = "event" + id;
    title = eventDetails.completeID.title;
}

var eventDetails = {
    'event1': {
        'title': 'Lisbon Earthquake',
            'content': "Test Content",
    },
        'event2': {
        'title': 'Falling Stars',
            'content': 'Test Content'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your method -

```
function getDetails(id) {
    completeID = "event" + id;
    title = eventDetails[completeID].title;
}
```

as an object property can be accessed using a [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

On a side note, in your `getDetails` function you are declaring your variables without the `var` keyword (unless they are already defined as globals). This will create them as global variables, and it is considered a very bad practice to use global variables this way. Try to declare them as follows -

```
function getDetails(id) {
    var completeID = "event" + id,
        title = eventDetails[completeID].title;

    // do whatever you want with the title
}
```

Comment: That did it!  I'll mark it as answered as soon as it lets me.  Thanks!